# Passing two different models to a view with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, partial-views, partial

I'm trying to set up a view that displays two different models.  For example, I have a "Details" view that shows details of a customer; which I am passing my customer model.  I also want to have a section on the page under the customer information (I was thinking about using a partial view) that lists their pets (for a vet practice).  I tried to set up a partial view and in the dialogue box I indicated to use the "pet" model, but was unsuccessfull in my attempt.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial view would be great for pets list. Just create an strongly typed .ascx as:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<PetList>" %>
```

Then display it from the main page.
You may wish to use the same pets list control on another pages.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that contains the Customer data and the Pet data:

```
public class CustomerDetailsViewModel
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public IList<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}
```

That is your model for the view.  Inside the view, use `Model.Customer` for your customer data and pass `Model.Pets` to your partial view which is strongly-type to `IList<Pet>`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a stongly typed view taking a type like

```
Pair<Customer, Pet> (or Pair(of Customer, Pet)) if using VB
```

or just pass a

```
Pair<Customer, Pet>
```

object in the view data object.

Then pass the Pet object to the partial view.